# What's different in App Engine SDK vs App Engine Production

Tags: php, google-app-engine, performance-testing

I am using the AppEngine SDK for developing a PHP based project. For the project I am using PageSpeed optimisations [1]. However when I compare the "Page Speed" results using the chrome developer toolbar [2] and I find the results very different.

Results in Development SDK
[image: PageSpeed results using SDK]

Results in Production
[image: PageSpeed results in Production]

So question is why is there a significant difference in page optimisation? Shouldn't the SDK behave identical (or at-least close) to production environment? What other differences should I need to be aware of during development. It is hard to test page optimisations if Development and Production behave differently.

[1] https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/

[2] https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gplegfbjlmmehdoakndmohflojccocli

Comment: How can it possibly perform the same, your dev environment is completey different to the production.  All you have is an almost complete matching set of API's.

Comment: You can't possibly test performance in dev - no auto scaling no large scale datastore implementation etc.... All you can do is profile you dev app to see what it is doing - though I have no idea what sort of profiling tools are available for PHP, my experience is with python.

Comment: ok, sorry I worded it wrongly, What I meant was if compression is enabled in production, then I would expect the same compression functionality working while using SDK. I am not expecting auto-scaling, replication and stuff.

Comment: What you have to realize is there is a bunch of other google infrastructure that also comes into play that the dev environment does not emulate, googles edge cache, various headers, some compression.  You still won't get a match unfortunately

Comment: Thanks @TimHoffman Thats the answer I was looking for. I guess I will have to live with not knowing if any page rendering optimisations are actually working unless I test it in production.

Comment: I would suggest setting up a test instance in google production environment for doing production profiling and experimentation without affecting your production env.  That is the best way for getting a handle on the specifics of the google production environment.   Also note the google production environment does change a lot (not in terms of basic stuff like headers, compression)  but edge cache, memcache longevity etc...

Answer (score 0):

The two environments have almost the same APIs, but one is running on your computer and the other is running on hundreds of servers and serving millions of users.

You are able to profile your app in development though.

Profiling can help you understand why the "Page Speeds" are slow in production, and show you where your need to improve your code.

Comment: I think you got that mixed up. "Page Speeds" are fast in production but slow in development (because compression is not happening). Unless "PageSpeeds" is optimised outside AppEngine, I don't see why it should be different.